# Recursive definition of cantor set.

Tags: cantor-set

According to Wikipedia, each step in the construction of the Cantor Set can be expressed recursively.

> Let $C_0=[0,1]$ and $C_{n+1} = \dfrac{C_n}{3} \bigcup\left(\dfrac{2}{3}+\dfrac{C_n}{3}\right)$.

Can someone explain how this even works?

To get $C_1$ form $C_0=[0,1]$ what does it even mean to write:

$C_{1} = \dfrac{[0,1]}{3} \bigcup\left(\dfrac{2}{3}+\dfrac{[0,1]}{3}\right)$?

Once I understand how this recursive formula even works, I would appreciate being shown how to prove that that this accurately describes the $n$th iteration of the construction of the Cantor set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notation
$$
\frac{[0,1]}{3} = \left\{\frac{t}{3}\;:\;t \in [0,1]\right\} ,
\\
\frac{2}{3} + \frac{[0,1]}{3} = \left\{\frac{2}{3}+\frac{t}{3}\;:\;t \in [0,1]\right\} .
$$
So
$$
\frac{[0,1]}{3} = \left[0,\frac{1}{3}\right] ,
\\
\frac{2}{3} + \frac{[0,1]}{3} = \left[\frac{2}{3},1\right] ,
\\
C_1 = \frac{[0,1]}{3} \cup \left(\frac{2}{3} + \frac{[0,1]}{3}\right)= \left[0,\frac{1}{3}\right]\cup \left[\frac{2}{3},1\right] .
$$